# Python using cusom Class into Main

Tags: python

i have developed a custom python script. I'm using main to run all script funtion. This is an example of strucure:

```
import ssl
import itertools
import decimal


def main():

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Now i have a specific class with different def that i need to use into main.
This example of Class that i have see on internet:

```
class GeoJSON:
"""GeoJSON class which allows to calculate bbox"""
def __init__(self, geojson):
    if geojson['type'] == 'FeatureCollection':
        self.coords = list(self._flatten([f['geometry']['coordinates']
                       for f in geojson['features']]))
        self.features_count = len(geojson['features'])
    elif geojson['type'] == 'Feature':
        self.coords = list(self._flatten([
                    geojson['geometry']['coordinates']]))
        self.features_count = 1
    else:
        self.coords = list(self._flatten([geojson['coordinates']]))
        self.features_count = 1

def _flatten(self, l):
    for val in l:
        if isinstance(val, list):
            for subval in self._flatten(val):
                yield subval
        else:
            yield val

def bbox(self):
    return [min(self.coords[::2]), min(self.coords[1::2]),
            max(self.coords[::2]), max(self.coords[1::2])]
```

Now i can use the GeoJson class and def into my main?

Thanks

Comment: The indentation in your code example is broken, please fix that.

Comment: I suggest you learn about the basics of object oriented programming. You need to learn how to create an instance of an object from a class and how to call methods on the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` function is not magical, you instantiate classes here in the same way as anywhere else.

```
class A():
    pass

def main():
    a = A()  # a is now an instance of A, you can create multiple instances
    b = A()
    a_third_instance = A()
```